# Offline Persistence Not working in Cloud Firestore in AngularJS (how to debug?)

Tags: angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to enable Cloud Firestore's disk persistence feature in an AngularJS web app, with mixed results. The data indeed remains if I disable the internet connection, but my edits to the database are not maintained when I reenable the connection.

I call `enablePersistence()` from `app.module.ts` (as suggested [here](https://alligator.io/angular/cloud-firestore-angularfire/)).

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,MatToolbarModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatIconModule, MatSidenavModule, MatListModule,    
   AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
   AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence(), /// <------- here's the call to enable persistence
   FirebaseUIModule.forRoot(firebaseUiAuthConfig),
```

To test it, I do these steps:

1. With internet on, load app
2. Turn on airplane mode
3. Click button to delete a document — this works, and I can confirm that from several different components.
4. Turn off airplane mode
5. After a brief pause the deleted item occurs again in the list.

(I get the same problem if I add or edit a document.)

I've tried this from Chrome and Firefox, with and without the developer console shown, and from a local and deployed version of the app.

Shortly after I reenable the internet connection, I get this error message in the console, which I am unfortunately not able to make sense of.

```
zone-evergreen.js:651 Unhandled Promise rejection: Missing or insufficient permissions. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:181062:28)
    at https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:204117:46
    at Y.<anonymous> (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:204061:21)
    at nb (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:206198:195)
    at Y.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.g.dispatchEvent (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:206196:304)
    at Z.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.Z.ua (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:206249:35)
    at Ad.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.g.Fa (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:206240:203)
    at ic (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:206204:371)
    at kc (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:206202:354)
    at M.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.g.Ja (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:206201:437) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:181062:28)
    at https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:204117:46
    at Y.<anonymous> (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:204061:21)
    at nb (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:206198:195)
    at Y.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.g.dispatchEvent (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:206196:304)
    at Z.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.Z.ua (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:206249:35)
    at Ad.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.g.Fa (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:206240:203)
    at ic (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:206204:371)
    at kc (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:206202:354)
    at M.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.g.Ja (https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/vendor-es2015.js:206201:437)
```

Comment: That's a problem with security rules rejecting a query. Please edit the question to show the specific query that's failing, and the rules that would affect it.

Comment: Do you mean the Firebase call that I made, which was then cached?

Comment: How are your firebase rules? maybe your app is losing the auth during the switch to online/offline somehow and if your rules do not allow unauthenticated users to interact, you will come across an `Missing or insufficient permissions` error. Please share them so we can take a look to further assist you

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a little late, but I leave this for future :

Make sure that you have not published two websites on `Firebase`
Make sure that you do not issue different permissions from the `databases`
The error occurs when there are two different requests from sites that you have applied and each site stores data that is different from the other.
Here is a simple example:

```
export interface Items {
  name: string;
  price: Price;
}
```

> Different requests:

```
export interface Items {
  name: string;
  price: Price;
  description: string;
}
```

You can now make sure that the data you pass through is not different from what you requested in another file or location